# Parse Firebase Auth error on Android

Tags: android, parsing, firebase, exception, firebase-authentication

i am using FirebaseAuth in my app and i try to parse properly Firebase error. I done it on old application same like this but i am not able to make it work in the new (and empty app).

I am already logged in my app, i disable my account from firebase portal (or change password) to intentionally unvalidated the current session on my mobile phone.

On the phone i do a "getIdToken" and Firebase fire an error (like excepted).

However Firebase fire a FirebaseException with a simple message "An internal error has occurred. [ USER_DISABLED ]"

So we got the error but we need to parse the string, not really proper...

In my old app firebase fired proper recognizable exception like "FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException" or "FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException" for bad credentials, etc..

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mAuth.getCurrentUser().getIdToken(true).addOnSuccessListener(getTokenResult -> {
   Log.d("GetToken", "token : " + getTokenResult.getToken());
}).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
   Log.d("GetToken", "error : " + e.getMessage() + ", " + parseFirebaseException(e));
});

ConnectionFailureReason parseFirebaseException(Exception exception) {
    try {
        throw exception;
    } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
        return ConnectionFailureReason.BAD_CREDENTIALS;
    } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException e) {
        // Thrown when performing an operation on a FirebaseUser instance that is no longer valid.
        switch (e.getErrorCode()) {
            case ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND:
                return ConnectionFailureReason.BAD_CREDENTIALS;
            case ERROR_USER_DISABLED:
                return ConnectionFailureReason.USER_DISABLED;
            case ERROR_USER_TOKEN_EXPIRED:
                return ConnectionFailureReason.SESSION_EXPIRED;
            case ERROR_INVALID_USER_TOKEN:
                return ConnectionFailureReason.SESSION_EXPIRED;
            default:
                return ConnectionFailureReason.SERVER_ERROR;
        }

.... //list of all exceptions available

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ConnectionFailureReason.UNKNOWN_ERROR;
    }
}
```

---

Edit:
I done some extra tests, in fact the issue seems to be only on the getToken (and on the old app too). So question is now, is it normal that GetTokenId return generic Exception while other firebase functions return specific exception ?

Comment: Same firebase version?

Comment: In my old app it's 11.6.2, in the new i tried 11.6.2 too and 11.8.0, same result...

Comment: Try making a new service account for the new application, since you have a recent version of firebase there which might have changes in authentication methods supported. It would be good for you to so the same and update firebase on the old one, but that's your choice.

Comment: It's seems to be a bug in firebase sdk, it's reported. Waiting for a fix

Comment: Do you have a link for the reported bug? Could not find something...

Comment: I discussed by mail with firebase support. They confirmed me that is bug in there side and it will be fix but without release date.

"Our engineers have confirmed that this is a bug on our end. This has already been brought to the attention of the right team and is being prioritized appropriately. However, I'm currently not able to share you any details or timelines as to when it could be fixed. Thanks for bringing this bug to our attention."